# How to evaluate a functional value with two argument vectors

Tags: r, function

I want to evaluate a likelihood function whose arguments are p and data, where p is 10x1 vector and data is 10x1 vector.
I want to optimize the function in R.
For initial parameter estimates I am writing par = c(p,data), where p and data has been specified in a vector. Whenever I run the optimization code, it gives me error

> 'Error in likelihood(par) : argument "data" is missing, with no default'.

Comment: You may need to convert this to a data frame. Use `df <- data.frame(p = p, data= data)`

Comment: @akash87 Can you please elaborate?  I used, df <- data.frame(p = c(0.8,0.3,0.1, 0.2,.03,.04,.05,.06,.3,.4), data= c(nj11,nj12,n1,n2)) and likelihood(df) gives error.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: optim() in R. @akash87

Comment: That is the function. What is the package?

Comment: stats.. @akash87

Comment: what is the function you are trying to optimize?

Comment: A likelihood function of 10 parameters.. should I write the df in the argument of function? like f = function(df) { ...}? @akash87

Comment: Nevermind about what I said earlier, I was thinking of something way different.

Comment: You can [edit] the post to include your code and data, where it will be more legible